# The app is disconnected after a second

Tags: r, shiny, r-markdown, shiny-server

I ran shiny app in linux.

I open the browser in the url: http://192.241.147.231:4949/sample-apps/MonitorUI/

The page is open but after a second disconnected.

I check the log file and it write to me this massage:

Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : 
  You are attempting to load an rmarkdown file, but the 
rmarkdown package was not found in the library. Ensure that 
rmarkdown is installed and is available in the Library of the 
user you're running this application as.
Calls: local -> eval.parent -> eval -> eval -> eval -> eval
Execution halted

I already downloaded the "rmarkdown" package. and it updated.

What is the problem? i don't find anything for this problem in the web.
the sample app that given by shiny-server package:http://192.241.147.231:4949/sample-apps/hello/ is working so what is the problem?

Thanks.

Comment: I get this error when I go on the page :`Error in library("RODBC") : there is no package called 'RODBC'`, did you install that package?

Comment: Yes, it wasn't easy. this made problems too. But I found something in the web.